# Why insert blank data into database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't understand the idea of inserting blank data into database, I have tried many examples from stack overflow and other many sites & forums but have never found my solution, please help me.

This my code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" class="incsub-mailchimp-field" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="incsub-mailchimp-submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>

<?php
 $email="";  

if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) 
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];
}

 // attempt insert query execution
 mysqli_query($mysqli, ("INSERT INTO email_list (email,created)
 VALUES ('$email',now())"));
?>
```

Comment: Because you're running the insert whenever the page is __viewed__, not just whenever it's submitted with data

Comment: Plus, `($mysqli, ("INSERT` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php >  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php no idea why you have all those extra unneeded brackets.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: There's more information in comments as to why their code's failing, than in the answer provided. *Hip hip hurray for low-quality and uninformative answers*, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $email="";  

if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) 
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];
 // attempt insert query execution
 mysqli_query($mysqli, ("INSERT INTO email_list (email,created)
 VALUES ('$email',now())"));
}
?>
```

Only insert into the database when field is POSTed.

Comment: You'll probably end up having more `if` clauses inside and each nested `if` will be slower. I prefer having the verification first and return if it's not ok before the processing code:
`if (!isset($_POST['subscribe'])) 
{
   exit; //or return
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
..........`

Comment: `if()... && !empty(){...}`

Comment: Thanks **BlunT** Now work properly :)

Answer (score 0):

you  checked isset(($_POST['subscribe']) but worte insert query outside of the if condition

```
<html>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="email" class="incsub-mailchimp-field" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required=""/>
<input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="incsub-mailchimp-submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
</html>
<?php
 $email="";  
if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) 
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO email_list (email,created) VALUES ('$email',now())");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by this method and i think it makes more sense

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <input type="email" class="incsub-mailchimp-field" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="incsub-mailchimp-submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>

<?php
 $email="";  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];   

 // attempt insert query execution
 mysqli_query($mysqli, ("INSERT INTO email_list (email,created)
 VALUES ('$email',now())"));
}
?>
```

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script. And use of `htmlspecialchars();` will prevent from cross site scripting attacks